# Check bash script argument against pattern, and replace a character in it

Tags: regex, bash, shell, posix, glob

I need to write a bash script that checks if the first argument supplied to the script matches a glob pattern, which in JavaScript RegExp I would express as

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$
```

In other words: starts with one or more alphabets/digits, followed by exactly one period, followed by 2 or more alphabets, and ends. Everything else should fail the test.

Then I also need to replace the period in the argument with an underscore.

So far I can check if the argument is empty:

```
case $1 in
  '') echo "No argument supplied" >&2; exit 1 ;;
esac
```

I figure the pattern test would need to be negated and put after the `''` check in that case statement, but I have no clue how to construct it. Any direct help or online resources would be greatly appreciated.

I would also like any help possible with how I can then change the valid argument supplied to replace the single period in it with an underscore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same regex works in BASH also. Consider this snippet:

```
re='^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$'
s='abc123.xy'

[[ $s =~ $re ]] && echo "${s/./_}"
abc123_xy
```

Comment: Appreciate that. I was able to remove the case statement and replace it with `if [[ $1 =~ $re ]]; then replaced="${1/./_}" else echo "Argument is empty or invalid" && exit 1 fi`